# resizing css animation dynamicaly

Tags: html, css, animation, browser, resize

I couldn't find any answer to that question. I have a css animation that I would like to resize dynamicaly with the browser window. Also, because it's combined of various separated elements, I would like it to maintain their space relation. 
I'm aware making a css animation instead of simple js animation is not the wisest and most optimal solution, but let me ask you just hipoteticaly - it that even possible? Resizing the css animation? I tried transform, but the resize is fixed, and I want a dynamical one.

What I have: http://world-of-krzakraft.strefa.pl/animate/animate.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are using fixed width. So no way to change it on window change. Use percentage width instead.

Comment: Yeah, but that's where the question comes from. I can't use percentage width when making css animation because weird stuff happens to it and doesn't resize anyway. I was wondering about OTHER way.

Comment: @magdazelena use jQuery instead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to do what your asking, you need to also add margins as percentage values as well. This way will ensure that all boxes stay a certain distance away from each other. It might also be useful to create containers with fixed percentage widths as well.